# Setting up Macro patterns with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, macros, pattern-matching

I am parsing more than 50 source files and some of them contain Macro Functions.
I have defined a FunctionCall and I am able to check if a program line is a function call, but nothing for macros and I also don't have a Macro collection. FunctionCall can be checked because after the function name follows the opening paranthese. Example of a macro I have:

```
TimerRetrigger_RTE_Uint8Uint8Uint16_Uint16Uint8
        (
        tmp3_ui8,
        tmp0_ui8,
        Mon2_T2KeyStrt_P,
        tmp4_ui16,
        tmp1_ui8
        );
```

Is there a way to set a pattern (e.g. with regex) and check if the program line is a Macro ? e.g. if the line is a string and the next row contains an opening paranthese ? I've edited the source file and got the opening paranthese next to the function name and it works, but I am not supposed to modify the source, sadly.

Comment: Are you using the [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag in your regex?

Comment: Tried the DOTALL in a regex and it seems it's still ignoring the lines and take just function calls. The thing is, I told my regex to match the program line, that's why I don't understand how python interprets the macro or how the compiler treats it. And now I face the same problem with CASTS